# Remote Testing Visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I have try to run the unit test using SSH (remote) in VS2022, the connection was successful but unable to run the unit test.
 It

> throws exception  `“StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: "path.........\.Dll"` must begin with the input root”

**My Settings**

Client PC and remote pc both run in windows 10.

.json file

```
{
  "version": "1",
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "ssh-connection",
      "type": "ssh",
      "remoteUri": "ssh://pc name :22"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a less restrictive localRoot directory (on the development machine) to be projected into the remote machine. Try using the parent of the solution folder instead of the solution folder, which it defaults to.

```js
{
  "version": "1",
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "ssh-connection",
      "type": "ssh",
      "remoteUri": "ssh://pc name :22",
      "localRoot": "X:\\Path\\To\\Parent\\Of\\Solution\\Folder\\"
    }
  ]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022