# Cannot run a Remote Test from VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, remote-debugging

I've followed the [official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022) on how to setup a remote testing environment in order to run .NET-based tests (MSTest unit tests, .NET Framework) in Windows 10 32-bit controlling/debugging them with VS2022 (17.3.4) from Windows 10 64-bit.
I've installed:

- OpenSSH server (I can connect with a ssh client)
- VS2022 Remote Debugger (remote debugging of a C++ executable works fine)
- VS2022 Test Agent (it starts interactively, but says it's disconnected, since no test controller is available)

[image: Test Agent Status]

The agent also shows the error when starting:
[image: Test Agent Start-up Message Box]

I've also installed the Test Controller, but couldn't configure it since it requires SQL Server Express...

Probably something else should also be installed, which is implied by "Remote tools SKU" in the official guidelines.

An attempt to discover tests always fails with the error like `System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Expected 20 bytes but only received 0 before the stream ended`, so no tests are visible in the Test Explorer, when I switch to the remote environment.
Content of `testEnvironments.json`:

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "environments": [
        {
            "name": "Windows10x32",
            "type": "ssh",
            "remoteUri": "ssh://Admin@VW10X32:22"
        }
    ]
}
```

Adding `"localRoot": "D:\\MyProjects\\MyApp"` (as suggested in [the answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75779500/536172)) has no effect.
Here is the complete log from the Output window:

```
Connecting to remote test environment using SSH at ssh://Admin@VW10X32:22/
Detected Windows remote environment.
Connected to test environment 'Windows10x32'
System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Expected 20 bytes but only received 0 before the stream ended.
   at Nerdbank.Streams.StreamExtensions.<ReadBlockOrThrowAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nerdbank.Streams.MultiplexingStream.V1Formatter.<ReadHandshakeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Nerdbank.Streams.MultiplexingStream.<CreateAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.RemoteServiceBroker.<ConnectToMultiplexingServerAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Host.TestPlatformProviders.SSHTestPlatformProvider.<ActivateSessionAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Host.TestPlatformAgentPool.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<<CreateRemoteAgentAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Utilities.EventPumpExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<<EnqueueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Host.TestPlatformProvider.<UpdateRuntimeEnvironmentsAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Logging.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__11`1.MoveNext()
```

According to this log something isn't responding properly and/or in time to the request.
Any hints on how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are targeting Windows but...

I had similar errors when trying to run remote unit tests on various Linux distribution (Ubuntu 22.04, Centos7.9, AlmaLinux9.2) with Visual studio 2022 - running locally on Hyper-V

All initial setup was failing until I figured out that some tools where required to make it work: (hinted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022)

- dotnet runtime (obviously)
- openssl-server (obviously)
- unzip (this was missing in all the distrib)
- curl
- fuse3-lib (missing in all distrib)
- tar (this was missing in Alma)

I don't know for Windows but you can definitely look in the direction of missing (undocumented) toolset.

Hope this helps